# Proving strict order for sets when elements are strict order

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Some relation A is strict order over a set.

A relation B is defined over the set's powerset.

Relation B holds when for two sets, every element of each set is related by A.

How do we prove that B is strict order as well?

I've tried to use Cartesian product, etc., but the answer doesn't seem to follow intuitively. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "every element of each set is related by $A$"?

Comment: The relation B holds when: XBY if Y ≠ Ø and for every x ∈ X and y ∈ Y, we have xAy.

Comment: What is $R$? And is $A$ total or partial?

Comment: Sorry. Corrected it now. A is total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X, \prec)$ be a strict total order. Define $(\mathcal P(X), \prec^*)$ by $U \prec^* V$ iff $\forall x \in U \forall y \in V \colon x \prec^* y$.

(Note that $\prec$ is your $A$ and $\prec^*$ is your $B$.)

Then $\prec^*$ is total only in trivial cases: If $X$ contains at least $3$ elements, say $u \prec v \prec w$, consider $U = \{u,w\}$ and $V = \{v \}$. Clearly $U \not \prec^* V$ and $V \not \prec^* U$, thus $\prec^*$ isn't total.

---

edit: Actually, this holds even if $X$ contains only two elements (as long as $\prec$ is strict) $u \prec v$. Then consider $U = \{u,v \}$ and $V = \{v\}$.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what this means: (X,≺)

Comment: "$(X,\prec)$ is a strict total order" means that $X$ is a nonempty set, $\prec \subseteq X \times X$ is a binary relation that is irreflexive, asymmetric, transitive and total. By an abuse of notation however, I write $u \prec v$ instead of $(u,v) \in \prec$.

Comment: I'm just unclear on how this proves that B is also strict order.

Comment: On the contrary - I prove that $B$ (i.e. $\prec^*$) is not total, if $X$ contains at least $2$ elements.